# CountDownTimer.cancel() is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, timer

`CountDownTimer.cancel()` is not working in the below code:

```
myTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    public void onFinish() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(null != myObject){
            myTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

In the above code I have started a `CountDownTimer` which check if the object is not `null` and cancels the Timer accordingly. The object is set by some listener at any point of time.
Please refer and suggest. Am I doing the right thing here?

> **Solution By Gautier Hayoun** :
>
> Just made a drop-in replacement for
>   CountDownTimer that you can cancel
>   from within onTick : [Github link](https://gist.github.com/737759)–
>   Gautier Hayoun Dec 12 '10 at 1:04

Comment: The problem might be that you are referencing `myTimer` inside the newly created object. Try `this.cancel();` instead of `myTimer.cancel();`.

Comment: is this a Android bug? I am really frustrated because of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution By Gautier Hayoun :**

Just made a drop-in replacement for CountDownTimer that you can cancel from within onTick : [Github link](https://gist.github.com/737759)– Gautier Hayoun Dec 12 '10 at 1:04

Comment: The handler in this gives warning 'This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur'.. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler

Answer (score 5):

Instead of CountDownTimer use `TimerTask`

```
final static long INTERVAL=1000;
final static long TIMEOUT=10000;


TimerTask task=new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                elapsed+=INTERVAL;
                if(elapsed>=TIMEOUT){
                    this.cancel();
                    displayText("finished");
                    return;
                }
                //if(some other conditions)
                //   this.cancel();
                displayText("seconds elapsed: " + elapsed / 1000);
            }
        };
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, INTERVAL, INTERVAL);

private void displayText(final String text){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextField.setText(text);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the probem in count down?

Comment: CountDown has some problems with canceling, usually if you call cancel() it will not be stopped and you will have 2 timers working at a time