# Problems To Cancel A CountDownTimer Android Java

Tags: java, android, back, countdowntimer

When I close my app by pressing the BACK button (onBackPressed() called), the `CountDownTimer` doesn't stop, until it is done with counting. How can I put the `CountDownTimer` **cancel();** in my `onBackPressed()`?

Because, when I quit my application (shown below with descriptions) I don't want counter toasts on my screen anymore.

**On top of my code:**

```
boolean network_connected = false;
```

**What's in my `onCreate()`:**

```
if (check_network.isInternetAvailable(this)) {
    network_connected = true;
    new connect_task_main().execute("");
} else {
    network_connected = false;
}

if (network_connected == false) {
    new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            global.toast.setText("No Internet Connection!" + "\n" + "Automatic Refresh In: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000); //set text for toast
            global.toast.show(); //show toast
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (network_connected == false) {
                global.cancel_toast(0); //stop all toasts
                finish(); //quit activity
                startActivity(new Intent(main_activity.this, main_activity.class)); //start activity
            } else {
            }
        }
    }.start(); //start the countdowntimer
} else {
    network_connected = true;
}
```

**`onBackPressed()`** method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (page_number > global.page_number_min) { //does not matter
        page_number--; //does not matter
        global.cancel_toast(0); //stop all toasts
        network_connected = true;
        finish();
    } else {
        global.cancel_toast(0);
        network_connected = true;
        finish(); //quit activity
        super.onBackPressed(); //quit application
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324484/28557

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a global object of `CountDownTimer` eg.

***On top of the main_activity class set: `CountDownTimer timer;` after that do the things below.***

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) 
        {
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
           {
             global.toast.setText("No Internet Connection!" + "\n" + "Automatic Refresh In: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000); //set text for toast
             global.toast.show(); //show toast
           }

           public void onFinish() 
           {
              if (network_connected == false) 
              {
                 global.cancel_toast(0); //stop all toasts
                 finish(); //quit activity
                 startActivity(new Intent(main_activity.this, main_activity.class)); //start activity
              }
              else 
              {
              }
          }
      }.start(); //start the countdowntimer
}
```

and on `onBackPressed` call `timer.cancel();` like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if (page_number > global.page_number_min) 
  { //does not matter
    page_number--; //does not matter
    global.cancel_toast(0); //stop all toasts
    network_connected = true;
    finish();
  }
  else
  {
    global.cancel_toast(0);
    network_connected = true;
    finish(); //quit activity
    super.onBackPressed(); //quit application
  }

 timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: You mean this? CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) { //code } and in my onBackPressed { countDownTimer.cancel(); }

Comment: Yeah use a global object there

Comment: Now it works great, forgot to set CountDownTimer timer; on top of my main class. Thanks @Apoorv